# Washed out render

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am modifying this file and all my renders turn out washed out. What should I do? Please help!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bmhmHlWB1GkSpX8QEOEGYq6OvPEC7cq-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you post a render?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QddQ_57PCj4FBCDC67BAXmj8uAPEeeqw/view?usp=sharing

For lighting, I am using a sun with the strength of 5 and sky texture for the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to render properties and Under Bloom increase the threshold till you like how it looks.
[image]
Threshold is basically at what point will the bloom kick in/ increase.

Comment: Thank you so much!